# Not able to access data in realtime database in node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access data from firebase real-time database.

This is my database:

[image]

This is my Code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/SAKSHI/NODEJS/Parking System/serviceAccount.json");
// var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "***********",
});

 try {
    // database.ref().child('/users').on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    //   for(const data in snapshot){
    //     console.log(data);
    //   }
    // });
    const database = admin.database();
    var ref = database.ref("/users/");
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

```
Versions
 "firebase": "^9.6.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
```

Update:
When I try to push the data it is returning reference but do not pushing and fetching data

```
 const newReference = database.ref(`/users${token}`).push();

  console.log("Auto generated key: ", newReference.key);

  newReference
    .set({
      nameplate: nameplate,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Data updated."))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Here, I am not able to fetch any data. It is not showing anything. Plz look into the issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you set up your config correctly? Any errors in the console? What version of firebase? Need more info.

Comment: Edited my code.. And there are no error in console